# Why a `Missing = inserted for \ifnum` error for empty l3seq sequences?

Tags: conditionals, expl3, latex3, xparse

I'm trying to use `expl3` sequences in order to stored 0, 1 or more affiliations to 1 or more authors stored in a `datatool` database. The following MWE works nicely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{datatool}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DTLnewdb{_mymodule_authors}

\seq_new:N \g_mymodule_author_affiliations_seq

\keys_define:nn { mymodule/authors }
{
  affiliation .code:n = \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_mymodule_author_affiliations_seq {#1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \_mymodule_authors:nn
{
  \DTLnewrow{_mymodule_authors}
  \DTLnewdbentry{_mymodule_authors}{name}{#1}
  \DTLnewdbentry{_mymodule_authors}{affiliations}{#2}
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \_mymodule_authors:nn { nV }

\RenewDocumentCommand \author { o m } {
  \IfValueTF {#1}
  {
    \keys_set:nn { mymodule/authors } { #1 }
    \_mymodule_authors:nV {#2}{\g_mymodule_author_affiliations_seq}
  }
  {
    \_mymodule_authors:nV {#2}{\c_empty_tl}
  }
  \seq_gclear:N \g_mymodule_author_affiliations_seq
}

\NewDocumentCommand \showauthors {  } {
  \DTLforeach*{_mymodule_authors}{
    \l_tmpa_tl=name,
    \l_tmpa_seq=affiliations
  }{
    \mymodule_display_author:nn {\l_tmpa_tl}{\l_tmpa_seq}
    \DTLiflastrow{
    }{
      \DTLpar
    }
  }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_author:nn
{
  #1
  \seq_if_empty:NF {\l_tmpa_seq}
  {
    \space(\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ,~ })
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
%\author{Foo, Bar 0}
\author[affiliation=Blah]{Foo, Bar 1}
\author[affiliation=Bleh,affiliation=Blih]{Foo, Bar 2}
\author[affiliation=Bloh,affiliation=Bluh,affiliation=Blyh]{Foo, Bar 3}
%
\showauthors
\end{document}
```

But, as soon as I comment out `\author{Foo, Bar 0}`, the author with 0 affiliation, I'm facing the following error I don't understand:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   {
```

Comment: A sequence cannot be used for the `V` argument.

Comment: @egreg But it seems to work as soon as the sequence is not `\c_empty_tl`.

Comment: It *seems* to work. Page 28 of `interface3` says “The `V` type returns the value of a register, which can be one of `tl`, `num`, `int`, `skip`, `dim`, `toks`, or built-in TeX registers.”

Comment: The list should be updated, but as far as I know, using sequences for `V` is unpredictable. I tried using `\c_empty_seq` rather than `\c_empty_tl`, but errors are thrown nonetheless.

Comment: Indeed, the `V` type can only be used where there is some logical 'value' concept. That simply isn't the case for a sequence.

Comment: @egreg Ooops, I meant `\c_empty_seq` instead of `\c_empty_tl` (in my numerous tests, I tried first the former and then the latter, hence the typo). Maybe I should I edit my question in order to avoid unnecessary remarks about this...

Comment: @JosephWright Any hope with another type (another specifier)? Or should I consider a radically different way of doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sequence cannot be used as argument to a `V` specifier, because it hasn't a single unique value.

So, instead of storing a sequence in the database, you can store a *pointer* to a sequence. As pointer, I use the “stringified” version of the author's name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{datatool}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DTLnewdb{_mymodule_authors}

\seq_new:N \l_mymodule_author_affiliations_seq

\keys_define:nn { mymodule/authors }
 {
  affiliation .code:n = \seq_put_right:Nn \l_mymodule_author_affiliations_seq {#1}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \_mymodule_authors:n
 {
  \DTLnewrow{_mymodule_authors}
  \DTLnewdbentry{_mymodule_authors}{name}{#1}
  \DTLnewdbentry{_mymodule_authors}{affiliations}{\tl_to_str:n{#1}}
 }

\RenewDocumentCommand \author { O{} m }
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_mymodule_author_affiliations_seq
  \keys_set:nn { mymodule/authors } { #1 }
  \_mymodule_authors:n {#2}
  \seq_new:c { g_mymodule_affiliation_ \tl_to_str:n{#2} _seq }
  \seq_gset_eq:cN { g_mymodule_affiliation_ \tl_to_str:n{#2} _seq } \l_mymodule_author_affiliations_seq
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \showauthors {  }
 {
  \DTLforeach*{_mymodule_authors}
   {
    \l_tmpa_tl=name,
    \l_tmpb_tl=affiliations
   }
   {
    \mymodule_display_author:VV \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl
    \DTLiflastrow { }{ \DTLpar }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_display_author:nn
 {
  #1
  \seq_if_empty:cF { g_mymodule_affiliation_#2_seq }
  {
   \c_space_tl(\seq_use:cn { g_mymodule_affiliation_#2_seq } { ,~ })
  }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mymodule_display_author:nn { VV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\author{Foo, Bar 0}
\author[affiliation=Blah]{Foo, Bar 1}
\author[affiliation=Bleh,affiliation=Blih]{Foo, Bar 2}
\author[affiliation=Bloh,affiliation=Bluh,affiliation=Blyh]{Foo, Bar 3}

\showauthors
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, as usual! I certainly won't be able to involve tricks such as `\tl_to_str` :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé That's to avoid problems with special characters in the name.

Comment: Your comment makes me think that your solution would fail in case of homonym authors (highly unlikely, for sure). Wouldn't it be possible to disambiguate the pointers, for instance with the help of `datatool`'s `\DTLcurrentindex` (arabic value of the current row counter)?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé The row counter might change from the moment the database is created to when it's used.